# select query to get result set with dynamic column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, datatable

i have following table and row and i require to get result set with table column have to be pass with day number of month date. i tried it but require assistance.

```
    CREATE TABLE HRTMR
(
  ENO      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)             NOT NULL,
  DAY1            VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),   DAY2            VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),   DAY3            VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY4            VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY5            VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  DAY6            VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY7            VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY8            VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY9            VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY10           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  DAY11           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY12           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY13           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY14           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY15           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  DAY16           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY17           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY18           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY19           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY20           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  DAY21           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY22           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY23           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY24           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY25           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  DAY26           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY27           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY28           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY29           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),  DAY30           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  DAY31           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)
)
insert into hrtmr values(
'0000000277', 'GS', 'GS','GS','GS', 'SS','O','GS','GS','GS','GS',   'GS','SS',  'O','GS','GS','GS','GS','GS','SS','O','GS', 'GS','GS',  'GS','GS',  'SS','O','GS','GS','GS','GS')

SELECT  'DAY' || to_number(to_char(to_date(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy'),'dd')) "DAY" FROM HRTMR Where ENO = '0000000277'
```

**above query result DAY10 but i require it to be a table column i.e 'DAY10' and result 'GS'** i am using oracle 11g for above case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can modify the name of yours columns DAY1 to DAY9 by DAY01 to DAY09

Second, you can change this `to_number(to_char(to_date(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy'),'dd'))` by `to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd'))`

Third, maybe you should try with a CASE WHEN :

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '01' THEN
            DAY01
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '02' THEN
            DAY02
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '03' THEN
            DAY03
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '04' THEN
            DAY04
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '05' THEN
            DAY05
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '06' THEN
            DAY06
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '07' THEN
            DAY07
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '08' THEN
            DAY08
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '09' THEN
            DAY09
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '10' THEN
            DAY10
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '12' THEN
            DAY11
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '12' THEN
            DAY12
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '13' THEN
            DAY13
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '14' THEN
            DAY14
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '15' THEN
            DAY15
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '16' THEN
            DAY16
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '17' THEN
            DAY17
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '18' THEN
            DAY18
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '19' THEN
            DAY19
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '20' THEN
            DAY20
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '21' THEN
            DAY21
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '22' THEN
            DAY22
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '23' THEN
            DAY23
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '24' THEN
            DAY24
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '25' THEN
            DAY25
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '26' THEN
            DAY26
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '27' THEN
            DAY27
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '28' THEN
            DAY28
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '29' THEN
            DAY29
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '30' THEN
            DAY30
        WHEN to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) = '31' THEN
            DAY31
    END "DAY"
FROM HRTMR Where ENO = '0000000277'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is dynamic SQL you need, if you want to do it that way. Here's how. Note the way I modified your `SELECT` statement (line #5); `sysdate` is a function which returns `date` datatype, so - you don't `to_date` it.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3    l_day varchar2(20);
  4  begin
  5    l_str := q'[SELECT  'DAY' || to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'dd')) FROM HRTMR Where ENO = '0000000277']';
  6    execute immediate l_str into l_day;
  7    dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || l_day);
  8  end;
  9  /
Result = DAY10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```